# Create and divide divs based on value using jquery or css

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating my first options page for my wordpress theme and I'm trying to create multiple child divs in 1 main parent div.

Basically if I type 1 it will create 1 100% div, if I type 2 it will create 2 50% divs, if I type 3 it will create 3 33.33% divs, this will go on and on.

I've not got any code at the moment but can jquery or css do a divide sum? I.e I click 3 it will do the sum 100 / the value (which will be 3 in this case) and echo the answer like width: answer;?

I'm not looking for someone to do my work for me, just some input as to how I can do it, but on the other hand, if you want to create a jsfiddle example I won't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand what it is that you're after... So (from my understanding) I'm going to assume:

1. You want to be able to enter a number into a `text` box
2. You want to create `div`s on the fly (inside a parent `div`/container)
3. You want the `div`s to be of the *same  and equal* size
4. Together the `div`s should span the width of the page

It's actually a fairly simple thing to accomplish.

### CSS

Firstly, we'll define some style rules for our generated `div`s

```
.generated{
    background:#2d2;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.generated:nth-child(even){
    background:#d22;
}
```

The `height` is just an example height.

The `background` colour(s) is set so that you can see the boxes; the `even` rule is so that you can easily tell which box is which (the `div`s will show up GREEN > RED > GREEN > RED...).

The `display` rule puts all of the `div`s on one line.

### JQuery

See comments for explanation:

```
$("#vin").on("change", function(){ // Create on change event
    var vin = $(this).val();       // Create and set variable for number of divs
    var cnt = 0;                   // Create the counter variable and set to 0
    $("#container").html("");      // Clear the container div
    while(cnt < vin){                                            // Loop while counter is less than number of divs
        $("#container").append('<div class="generated"></div>'); // Append div to parent container
        cnt++;                                                   // Increment counter
    }
    $(".generated").css("width", (100/vin)+"%"); // Update .generated css class with new width
})
```

### HTML

To keep this simple I'll just use a `text` input and a `div` container...

```
<input type="text" name="vin" id="vin">
<div id="container"></div>
```

### Putting it all together

http://jsfiddle.net/m3f9n/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .generated{
            background:#2d2;
            height: 100px;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .generated:nth-child(even){
            background:#d22;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#vin").on("change", function(){
                var vin = $(this).val();
                var cnt = 0;
                $("#container").html("");
                while(cnt < vin){
                    $("#container").append('<div class="generated"></div>');
                    cnt++;
                }
                $(".generated").css("width", (100/vin)+"%");
            })
        })
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="vin" id="vin">
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that but it's pretty simple math.. 100 divided by the amount of divs will give you the right percentage.

`100 / $('.class').length` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to jquery and I thought something like this maybe the case but didn't know how.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to target [modern browser only](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), you could also use a `flexbox` layout.

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmhyz (tested on Fx27 and Chrome33)

Markup

```
<section>
  <div>1</div>
</section>  

<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</section>  

<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section { 
  display: flex; /* here you set a flex container */
  width: 400px; 
  margin: 30px; 
  border: 2px #ccc dashed; 
}

div {
  border: 1px #666 solid;
  flex-grow: 1; /* this set equal width to all divs
                   so they fill the available space */

}
```

Resulting effect

[image]

---

Anyway, if your browser doesn't support the flexbox layout. you could do a simple feature detection (with `Modernizr` library) and then set the width to your divs with a js fallback at *domready* event, e.g.

```
if (!Modernizr.flexbox) {
   /* set the equal width to all elements of you wrapper */
}
```

([further information](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare multiple width classes and use them. Like this:

If you have max 12 colums you may do this:

```
.twelve.columns
{
    Width:100%;
}

.eleven.columns
{
    Width: 91.666%;
}
```

Either Way, regarding you question:

You can use calc to calculate with css. You can use:

```
.six.columns
{
    Width:calc(100% / 6);
}
```

You may also use Things like this: `calc(80% - 20px)`